# What is the problem with the dynamic import when it is called from a node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get an object of a class in Node.js, though my approach encounters a problem which I do not understand!

**Server.js** :

```
app.post('/users',(req,res)=>{

   let resolvedFunction = require("./src/util/entity-object-resolver/entity-object-resolver");  
   let obj = resolvedFunction(); 
});
```

**entity-object-resolver**:

```
function getUserValidationObject(){   

    let UserValidation = import('../validation/user-validation');
    return new UserValidation();    
}
module.exports = getUserValidationObject;
```

**UserValidation Class:**

```
import {checkEmailFormat, checkUserName, checkNameFormat} from "../regex/string-regex";
import ErrorMessage from "../../resource/text/error-message";

export class UserValidation {
    /*This is a class which has some useful methods!*/
```

**Problem**:

It seems when it wants to `import` the `UserValidation` class, it encounters a problem. Finally, the following exception is thrown and printed on the console!

> UnhandledPromiseResjectionWarning: Error: Not supported at **getUserValidationObject**

As I said, I think there is a problem with the dynamic import, because when I comment this line, no exception is thrown. So, can you tell me what the problem is?

**Suspicious line**:

```
 let UserValidation = import('../validation/user-validation');
```

Comment: Why are you using `import()` instead of `require()`?

Comment: I believe we use require function when we want to get a module inside the Node.js server. My class is also used in the front, and this is the reason it has used export keyword. So, I think that I am allowed to import it somewhere outside the Node.js server. It shouldn't have any problem. @HereticMonkey

Comment: import returns you a promise (async loading), require returns you what is actually exported (sync loading). Chain your import call with then and catch.

Comment: So, you may want to [edit] your question to include that tidbit of information, because it is relevant. You may also want to include what version of NodeJS you are running.

Comment: @RahulPadalkar Or use `await`... :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes. Not a fan of async/await though :)

Comment: @RahulPadalkar It seems that we are not allowed to chain require and dynamic import together! Have you ever heard something like this !?

Comment: No actually, can you point to any resource where you learned it?

Comment: official documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs isn't excluding "chaining" ... CJS loading CJS -> require() ... CJS loading MJS/ESM -> await import() ...